# Oracle Procedure to return count as a word

Tags: oracle, count, procedure

I am tryin to create a procedure that takes in a table value (varchar2), counts the number of times it occurs, and then returns a statement telling the user how many times it is in table in a word rather than as a number (three rather than 3).
The code I have so far is:

`create or replace procedure user_search (x in varchar2) is y int;`

`begin`

`select count(*) as z into y from userpermissions where x=username;`
`dbms_output.put_line(to_char(y) || ' document(s) found under user: ' || x);`

`exception`

`when no_data_found then dbms_output.put_line('no documents for user: ' || x);`

`end;`

when i run this, it will say 'pl/sql procedure completed successfully' , but not return anything. Trying to figure out what i am doing wrong here, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing several things wrong.

The immediate question ("not return anything") has nothing to do with your procedure; you need to run `set serveroutput on` first, to turn on the displaying of the `dbms_output` buffer to the screen after the procedure completes. Have you done that?

Your exception will never be reached; if `x` is not found as a username in your table, the query still returns a row: the count will be zero in that case. If you must treat this as an exception (and/or use the word "none" instead of the word "zero") you will need to handle that differently.

Once you start seeing your output, you will notice that `to_char(<number>)` doesn't magically convert the number into its English representation as a word. Did you think it did, or do you know how to change that, and at this stage you were just testing what you got so far?

If you need help with this last part, here's a hint:

```
select deptno, to_char(to_date(count(*), 'j'), 'jsp') as english_num
from   scott.emp
group  by deptno
;

    DEPTNO ENGLISH_NUM    
---------- ---------------
        30 six            
        20 five           
        10 three
```

If you don't understand how that works, check out the 'j' and 'jsp' format models for `to_date()` and `to_char()`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It took a little trial and error, but i was able to get the first part working (still working on the exception). I thought i had done server output on, but i must have missed it or something like that. Thanks for the help

Comment: @dyertkd - if you do need to throw an exception when the count is 0, you **can** do that (and the exception is exactly the one you have already) - you just need to change the `SELECT` statement: add `group by null` at the end. You may want to play with that in plain SQL first: compare `select count(*) from dual where 0 = 1` against `select count(*) from dual where 0 = 1 GROUP BY NULL`. Note that group by `NULL` is not really the point; group by any hard-coded constant, like `group by 22` or `group by 'x'` - they all do the same thing.